# “... takes as input ...” vs “... takes input as ...”

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, programming, particle-shift

Why did the author place "as" between the verb *take* and the preposition here?

> Give an efficient algorithm that *takes **as** input* a desired accuracy ϵ > 0 and returns a simple cycle C for which r(C)≥ r*-ϵ.

Can we just simply read it as:

> Give an efficient algorithm that *takes input **as*** a desired accuracy ϵ > 0 and returns a simple cycle C for which r(C)≥ r*-ϵ.

Comment: What do you think *as* is doing in this sentence that would allow you to invert the syntax without a change in meaning?

Comment: i just would like not to miss anything that author trying to say and try to learn any new usage of as.

Comment: It seems to me asking this question in computing or mathmatics may  > the yield  of an answer.

Comment: *Takes as input* is the conventional phrasing. Think of it as a structured form of English that corresponds to the more formal expression of the algorithm in a programming language.

Comment: @GlobalCharm, So What is the meaning of it in every-day language? I do know that "this kind" of questions seem really stupid, but for someone who learn English as their "second" language just seem like want to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

The expression *take as input* is similar in concept to *take as given*, which has an entry of its own in the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20(something)%20as%20given).

In the discussion of an algorithm, sometimes we want to focus on the general logic as opposed to the specifics of a particular calculation. We identify some things as constants (pi=3.1416), some things as rules to follow in the calculation, and other things *as input*. We can then talk about the properties of the algorithm, e.g. that perhaps its speed of execution goes up when the value of the input goes down.

To put this in a larger context: A fundamental model of computation is the [Turing Machine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), which has *input*, *output*, *state* and *transition rules*. The expression *takes as input* has become the conventional form because people have been talking and writing about computer algorithms for many decades now, and distinguishing between *input* and *state* is often an important part of the discussion.